# framework not found CometChatSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, cometchat

I have integrated CometChat Ready UI SDK in my iOS App. But when I try to build the code at that time I am getting following linker error **ld: framework not found CometChatSDK** 
[image]

Following things I have added in my project

1) Framework search path is set to **$(PROJECT_DIR) -> recursive** [image]

2) I have added  **-all_load , -ObjC , -lc++**  in **Other Linker Flag** [image]

3) **Cometchat SDK** is also showing in the **Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binaries with Libraries** [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found following solution form the cometChat support team.

1) Change **CometChatSDK.framework** name to **MessageSDKFramework.framework**

2) Change your Import Statement **`#import<CometChatSDK/MessageSDK.h>`** to **`#import<MessageSDKFramework/MessageSDK.h>`**

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in beginner's guide of cometchat: https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/ios-chat-sdk/custom-ui/initial-setup/

Put the following in your Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries:

- SystemConfigurarion.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- libxml2.dylib
- libz.dylib

Next, Click on Targets → Your app name → and then the ‘Build Settings’ tab. Scroll down to the ‘Linking’ section, and double-click to the right of where it says ‘Other Linker Flags’. Click on the “+” button to add the following:

- ObjC
- all_load

Try semantic import if everything fail.

Comment: I have added all the dependent libraries and linker flags in my project but it is not working.

Comment: I just updated the link of cometchat's guide. Please check it step by step. You did the right thing in your step #1.

Comment: I have tried your solution but still it is showing the same error and semantic import is also not working. Is any thing I did wrong in my #2 and #3 step?